# Passing variable between PHP and JS within same HTML

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am reading data from MySQL using PHP. I am then trying to pass that data to the JS below within the same HTML, using it on OpenLayer maps. I have tried various methods including json_encode but cannot seem to pass valid data. When I set the data manually in the JS it works OK. What am I doing wrong with the code? Is there a preferred method?

```
<html lang="en">
```

.map {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
      }
    
    
    OnTRack User Tacking

```
<?php
// ... Other database code removed for example...
$rowlon = 151.215324;
$rowlat = -33.856733;
?>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // var latestlon = <?php echo $rowlon; ?>;
    // var latestlat = <?php echo $rowlat; ?>;
    var latestlon = "<?php echo json_encode($rowlon) ?>";
    var latestlat = "<?php echo json_encode($rowlat) ?>";
    // var latestlon = 151.215324;
    // var latestlat = -33.856733;
    var mycoords = [latestlon, latestlat];
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(mycoords),
      zoom: 12
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you json_encode? That returns a string object not at all like your commented line below. You can always look at the HTML source and see what your code does

Comment: 1. Remove the double quotes while using echo - especially if you want to preserve the variable type (the module might be expecting a number type instead of string)
2. It's not necessary to use json_encode since the value is not in an array format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to the following reasons

**Reason - 1**

```
 var latestlon = "<?php echo json_encode($rowlon) ?>"; // Type = String
 var latestlat = "<?php echo json_encode($rowlat) ?>"; // Type = String
```

Change the JS variable to *type* number by removing the double quotes

```
 var latestlon = <?php echo json_encode($rowlon) ?>; // Type = Number
 var latestlat = <?php echo json_encode($rowlat) ?>; // Type = Number
```

**Reason - 2**

Please check if you are using php file extension

**FYI**: It is not necessary to use json_encode since the value is not an array.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. Reason 1 & 2. Most importantly I did not know the file had to have a PHP extension even though is had base HTML code. Thanks to all of the input from others too!

Answer (score 3):

```
var latestlon = <?=$rowlon?>;
var latestlat = <?=$rowlat?>;
```

You don't need double quotes here and especially json_*

If it doesn't work then you probably doing something other wrong, check browser console for errors.

Comment: Do not use short tags. They are not always supported.

Comment: @Andreas short open tags always available since php5.4(released 7 years ago): http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work... The code stops at that line and doesn't proceed to the mapping.

Comment: People are still using PHP 4. I saw a question about PHP 4 just yesterday. And that can be disabled? I just want your answer to be useful for everyone, not only those with 5.4+ and with the correct settings.

Comment: Console error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" This is for any of the options starting with = <?

Comment: @ChrisKing check you page source code, you probably have some problems with data that you try print so you get JS error.